# WCF unhandled exception by user code

Tags: c#, wcf, error-handling

I'm developing a WCF service with C# and .NET Framework 4.0.

I have the following code:

```
public long CreateUser(string userName)
{
    try
    {
        if ((userName == null) ||
            (userName.Equals(string.Empty)))
            throw new ArgumentNullException();

        ...

    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        resultCode = 3;
        throw ex;
    }

    ...

}
```

when userName == string.Empty debugger stops and a dialog said:

```
ArgumentNullException unhandled by user code.
```

How can I fix that?

**UPDATE**
I want to notify client that there was an error in server side.

Comment: I want to notify client that there was an error in server side.

Comment: side note: never use `throw ex`, use `throw` to rethrow an exception

Comment: well if you want to notify the client, the use the string.IsNullOrEmpty test and notify the client in whatever manner you choose.

Comment: This is a WCF. I think there is a way to notify client but I don't know how. This is why I've left `throw ex`.

Comment: Do not throw ex; You lose information that way. Instead you should simply write throw; that way you keep all information, stacktrace.

Answer (score 1):

You need to handle the exception when using the CreateUser method:

```
try
{
    myClass.CreateUser (user);

}
catch (ArgumentNullException ex)
{

}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think it would be best to just do something like this at the top of your method rather than create and throw an exception.

```
if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(userName))
{
  //handle
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think String.IsNullOrEmpty() is the most clear way; but I'm not sure I understand the question.

Your IF is working; and your code is throwing the exception.  So writting it with String.IsnullOrEmpty() won't change that.

Do you want to know how to 'handle' that exception?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to notify the client use [FaultException](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.faultexception.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

Handle the exception :-)

This is normal behavior.

Your client must call your method like so:

```
try {
   long result = myService.CreateUser(someVariable);
} catch (ArgumentNullException exc)
{
  // Your error-handling code here
}
```

If you don't want to handle the exception, but simply process the "error code" (which is a bad practice, definitely not recommended), then you should remove the "throw ex;" line from your code.

Answer (score 0):

First, you should know about String.IsNullOrEmpty(), it's useful in the case you provided.

Second, you are throwing an exception up the stack.  There needs to be a try/catch block further up that is catching the exception you're throwing.  Here, the try/catch is doing you no good.

```
public long CreateUser(string userName)
{
        if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(userName))
            throw new ArgumentNullException();

        ...
}
```

then elsewhere,

```
try 
{
     someClass.CreateUser(userName);
}
catch (ArgumentNullException ex)
{
  ... error handling code here
}
```